# PAGE GUI "expected boolean value but got ".top37 configure -"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working on a GUI in PAGE and get some kind of error, I can't replicate it unless I duplicate a .tcl and try and open it.

```
expected boolean value but got ".top37 configure -background #d9d9d9 -highlightbac"
    while executing
"if {!$vTcl(paste) && !$vTcl(redo)} {
                ::vTcl::MessageBox -message "Alias '$alias' already exists."  -title "Invalid ALias"  -icon error..."
    (procedure "vTcl:valid_alias" line 7)
    invoked from within
"vTcl:valid_alias $target $alias"
    (procedure "vTcl:DefineAlias" line 19)
    invoked from within
"vTcl:DefineAlias "$top.lab52" "Label1_5" vTcl:WidgetProc "f_sec" 1"
    (procedure "vTclWindow.top37" line 56)
    invoked from within
"vTclWindow.top37 .top37 "
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval "vTclWindow$name $newname $rest""
    (procedure "Window" line 18)
    invoked from within
"Window show .top37 $btop"
    (file "C:/page/userinfo.tcl" line 332)
    invoked from within
"source C:/page/userinfo.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $file]  "
    (procedure "vTcl:source" line 26)
    invoked from within
"vTcl:source $file newprocs"
    (procedure "vTcl:open" line 41)
    invoked from within
"vTcl:open"
    (menu invoke)
```

**Above is the Stack Trace**

I have been able to duplicate a file, and my purpose for duplication is because I want to have multiple Top Level windows and need some kind of symmetry in between each page.

Comment: We need some example code to work with. Just having your traceback is not going to help. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That's the thing, there is no code, it's PAGE - a GUI builder, and when I try to generate any kind of code it doesn't work because this error prevents it from doing so @Mike-SMT

Comment: Oh. I see. I have never used a GUI builder. It was always simple enough to build the GUI in the code. I will have to see if I can get the GUI builder and test it out.

Comment: I would've just built the GUI in the code but the client requested a kiosk application with specifics on using Python, a few APIs and a very distinct layout.

Comment: Tkinter is very capable of any layout design you may need. The `grid()` and `pack()` geometry managers will do most of what you need and the `place()` manager can take care of anything very specifically place that is difficult to manage with the other options.

Comment: I am not sure anyone here can help you. Your error comes from a GUI Builder and not from code you have written. Without having your exact version of PAGE and your layout no one can test and reproduce problem. I think you need to go to the PAGE github and report the issue and see if they can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Page you are presently working with does not work.  I had the same error message.  I had to go to sourceforge.net and click the "last update: 3 days ago".  Then I downloaded and reinstalled the latest program.  This fixed everything.